# How to display my tinymce text into my html view

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I save into my database the text which I write into a textarea with tinymce.
What I'm trying to do now, is to display this content into my view. Right now, when I'm doing `{{$article->contenu}}` i've this :

[image]

Is there a way to display my tinymce content into my view with the correct format please (not inside a textarea) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content from TinyMCE is saved as an HTML string. You are passing that HTML content to Laravel's templating engine as a variable, and asking it to to be rendered. By default Laravel does not automatically render HTML, to prevent XSS attacks.

However, if you use this syntax instead:

```
{!! $article->contenu !!}
```

...the content should render as expected. For more info, check the Laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data